# compact simple factors vs compact ideals

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a real semisimple Lie algebra. Then there are simple ideals $\mathfrak{g}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{g}_n \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$, unique up to order, such that
$$
\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathfrak{g}_n
$$
and every ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a sum of some of these simple ideals.

Are the following two statements equivalent?

1. each $\mathfrak{g}_i$ is noncompact
2. $\mathfrak{g}$ does not contain a nontrivial compact ideal

Clearly 2. implies 1., but I'm not sure about the converse. Here, a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is called *compact* if it is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group or equivalently, if $\text{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ is compact.

(Here, $\text{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ denotes the adjoint group of $\mathfrak{g}$, that is, the unique Lie group whose Lie algebra is the image of the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$.)

Comment: It would have been useful to specify that you are considering Lie algebras over the reals.

Comment: For the converse, what have you tried? What are the ideals of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: @YCor Thanks I have now edited the question. For the converse, my idea is that for $n=2$, if $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$ are noncompact then they are both not the lie algebra of a compact group. But if $\mathfrak{g}_1 \oplus \mathfrak{g}_2$ were the lie algebra of a compact group $G$, then somehow that would contain compact groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ those lie algebras are $\mathfrak{g}_1$ and $\mathfrak{g}_2$, in contradiction to the assumption.

Comment: Do you know if the statement is true? I couldn't find it written down anywhere. By an exercise in Helgason, a symmetric space is of noncompact type iff the lie algebra of its isometry group is semisimple and has no nontrivial compact ideals. So this would be reduced to "semisimple and noncompact".

Comment: What is the meaning of $\text{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ here?

Comment: @NoOne $\text{Int}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the so-called *adjoint group* of $\mathfrak{g}$. This is the unique Lie group whose Lie algebra is the image of the adjoint representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Properties)). I've now added an explanation to the question.